# IntelliJ rainbow brackets in Scala worksheets using

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I am looking for rainbow brackets in Scala worksheets in IntelliJ to achieve a similar result as  the [rainbow Vim plugin](https://github.com/luochen1990/rainbow). I installed IntelliJ's rainbow plugin but no colors..

Any suggestions how I could achieve this?

Configuration info:

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2.4
Build #IU-162.2032.8, built on September 9, 2016
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Power safe mode was on. I disabled power safe mode and coloring works!